# Ubuntu System Restarts Issues

Tags: nvidia, 22.04

My system restart automatically at least 12-15 times in a day. Someone please help me. My system configuration are as follows.

- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10400F CPU @ 2.90GHz
- Motherboard: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. Product Name: B460M D3H
- RAM: 24GB
- Graphic card: NVIDIA Corporation. Product: GK208B [GeForce GT 710]
- HDD: Seagate BarraCuda 3.5. Device Model: ST1000DM010-2EP102. Serial Number:    ZN1J8S11

Comment: what does your logs show at the time of restarts.

Comment: If your hardware is enterprise & server grade, machine logs are where its best to look (*no such logs will exist on consumer grade, esp. laptop/desktops*). As per first comment; OS systemd logs will provide a clue if the OS was involved in the restart; but nothing will be evident IF the hardware rebooted itself (eg. PSU, RAM, motherboard due to heat caused the shutdown - machine logs are needed to read reason for that though some clues maybe evident for *heat* in systemd journals too)